# Not able to get Swagger UI with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am following the article at http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/documenting_your_spring_api_with.

Everything works fine but not able to integrate Swagger UI.

```
http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html
```

results in /error redirection.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am not following that blog post as things have changed a lot, but I am not getting it working either. See https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc for updated instructions

Comment: I have everything working properly with SpringBoot (although it took quite some time!) Where are you up to and I will try and help

Comment: I got it working but dont remember the root cause

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. going to http://localhost:8080/rest/swagger/index.html gives /error redirection. http://localhost:8080/rest/api-docs/ gives me correct raw json. I have put dist folder into src/main/resources/static folder too and renamed it swagger

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but maybe this will help someone with the similar problem in the future.

I followed similar tutorial to the one you mentioned and I made it work without a problem. I put my own document on how to setup a Swagger with UI in a Spring boot project couple of weeks ago. Maybe it will help you out since it is shorter and more up-to-date.

**Add Maven dependencies**

Stick these in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
 <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.2</version>
 <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

**Add Swagger UI**

Download the [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) from github. Copy the `dist` folder into your `webapp` directory and rename `dist` to `swagger` (or any name you like).

Open the *index.html* file inside the copied directory and change the url in the first javascript function so it points to the `/api-docs endpoint`:

```
var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
  url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
  url = "/project-name/api-docs";
 }
```

**Configure Swagger**

Create a *SwaggerConfig.java* class and configure swagger there:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SwaggerConfig {
  private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;
  @Autowired
  public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
    this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
  }
  @Bean
  public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
    return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
    // Root level documentation
    .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Swagger-demo JSON API", "This service provides a JSON representation the service API", null, null, null, null))
    .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
    // Map the specific URL patterns into Swagger
    .includePatterns("/greeting.*");
  }
}
```

Your swagger should be up and running now. Try accessing `/project-name/swagger/index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this with swagger2 configuration inside a gradle based spring boot application. Following are the configuration required for Swagger2.

**Add Gradle Configuartion**

Add Gradle dependencies inside build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.2")
    }
```

**Swagger2 Confugration Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
  @Bean
  public Docket userApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().pathMapping("/")
        .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
        .alternateTypeRules(newRule(
            typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
            typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
            newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build()))
        .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey())).securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
        .apiInfo(apiInfo());
  }

  @Autowired
  private TypeResolver typeResolver;

  private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("mykey", "api_key", "header");
  }

  private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
        .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/anyPath.*")).build();
  }

  List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return newArrayList(new SecurityReference("mykey", authorizationScopes));
  }

  @Bean
  SecurityConfiguration security() {
    return new SecurityConfiguration("123456", "test-app-realm", "clientapp", "apiKey");
  }

  @Bean
  UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return new UiConfiguration("validatorUrl");
  }

  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("DSM API", "API for DSM", "1.0.0", "termsOfServiceUrl",
        "nijo@ndimensionz.com", null, null);
    return apiInfo;
  }

}
```

**Add Swagger UI**

Download the [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) from github. Copy the dist folder into your ***src/main/resources/static*** directory and rename dist to swagger

**HomeController.class**

```
@Api(basePath = "/", value = "/", description = "Home Controller")
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
  }

}
```

**MyApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SwaggerConfig.class)
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }


}
```

Configure your spring boot application with dependencies and run to see the API.

the url will be http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger-ui.html
you can also customize this as above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I too face same problem. I was able to see json but not swagger ui after adding dest folder aslo. In initialize class which extends **SpringBootServletInitializer** I added below method then it was working perfect

```
    @Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SampleWebStaticApplication.class);
}
```

please refer [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static/src/main/java/sample/web/staticcontent/SampleWebStaticApplication.java)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working configuration incase it helps anyone else

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!production"})
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host("localhost")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, Date.class)
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return "/docs";
                    }
                })
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Since I am also using Spring security, I also had to add the following to my whitelist:

```
private String[] swaggerWhiteList = {"/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger.json", "/webjars/**"};
```

Then I could access it using the following url:

http://localhost:8080/docs/swagger-ui.html