# swagger ui not working for swagger version 2

Tags: tomcat7, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am currently working on a project involving spring-boot and swagger. I have upgraded my maven spring boot project to the latest Swagger using the link [Upgrade to version2](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/docs/transitioning-to-v2.md).
I am currently using the Swagger-UI which I have configured from the link [Swagger-UI with Spring Boot](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-swagger-ui)

I try to access the url : localhost:8080/swagger/index.html after deploying the app successfully on my tomcat server. Unfortunately, it does not work and I am unable to view the swagger-ui in my browser. How do I go on about it further?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it does not work" ?  What do you see.  Open developer tools in your browser - are json files being downloaded?

Comment: Nope, the JSON files are not being downloaded. Initially, I was able to do it. After upgrading, it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34808180/1559147 This might help you out on this.. I have used gradle in my solution, but its not a   problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing the documentation of 2 versions of the library. The second link points to an older version of the springfox library. Please follow the instructions in the latest snapshot of [the documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/). If you've configured everything correctly you should see the swagger-ui at http://localhost:8080[/CONTEXT-PATH]/swagger-ui.html. Depending on how you've set your springboot app the context path is optional.